# Как обратиться к словарю по имени элемента?

Tags: python, списки

Язык python.
В общем у меня словарь, допустим с таким содержимым :

`test = {'101' : 3, '11' : 2, '100110' : 1}`

Т.е пользователь вводит какую-то инфу, она переводится в двоичный вид, считается кол-во символов (collections.Counter) и на выходе получаем словарь, пример которого я описал выше.
Прекрасно знаю, что нельзя обращаться к словарям по индексам (0, 1, 2, 3...), но мне нужно получить значения первого элемента списка, при том, что я не знаю его 'имя'.
К примеру:

```
import someModule
from collections import Counter
count_of_words = Counter(test_string)
print(count_of_word.someModule.someMethod('0'))
```

Надеюсь, вы поняли.

Comment: Что именно вы считаете **первым** элементом?

Comment: В данном случае с словарём test, ключ '101'. В любом случае нашёл решение : for elem in dict: print(dict[elem])

Comment: у вас на разных машинах и версиях питона может выскакивать разный элемент "первым", Используйте OrderedDict для гарантии

Comment: Еще зависит от версии python, которую вы используете, словари стали упорядоченными в 3.6 (побочный эффект, а по факту в 3.7), варианты с `iter`,  `test.keys()[0]` и тому подобное в версиях ниже работать не будут, но начиная с 3.6 можно и так, но `OrderedDict` конечно лучше

Answer (score 1):

```
test = {'101': 3, '11': 2, '100110': 1}

print(next(iter(test)))
```

Так?

Или можно привести ключи к списку

`print(list(test.keys())[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать список ключей, к которым ты по индексам в списках будешь обращаться к словарю.

```
# Допустим тебе нужно распечатать значения этих ключей
test = {'101': 3, '11': 2, '100110': 1}
keys = [k for k in test]  # Создал список ключей 
for i, key in enumerate(keys): # Обращаешься к ключам в списке
    print(test[keys[i]])
```